# Centering Text Over HTML Video

Tags: html, css

I have added a small video background to my website, and added some text over the top. However, I can't centre the text in the middle of my video. Can anyone help? See my code below.

```css
.header-unit {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

#video-container {
  position: absolute;
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video-container p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
  <div id="video-container">
    <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
      <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add 2 lines to this rule:

```
     #video-container p {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 1;
       font-size: 50px;
       color: white;

     width:100%;
     text-align:center

     }
```

if you give 100% width to the absolute positioned paragraph you can easily use `text-align: center` on it

```css
.header-unit {
           height: 80px;
           border: 2px solid #000;
           border-right: none;
           border-left: none;
        margin-top: 50px;
           position: relative;
           padding: 20px;
         }

         #video-container {
           position: absolute;
         }

         #video-container {
           top:0%;
           left:0%;
           height:100%;
           width:100%;
           overflow: hidden;
         }

         #video-container p {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: white;
         width:100%;
         text-align:center
         }

         video {
           position: relative;
           z-index: 0;
         }
         video.fillWidth {
          width: 100%;
         }
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
            <div id="video-container">
          <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
                <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
                  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method #1

1. Offsetting position within containing element with `left` and
   `right` property values of `0`
2. Centering text with `text-align: center`
3. Vertically centering with `transform: translateY(50%)`

**Example:**

```
video-container p {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: black; /* for the sake of demonstration */
      /* additional */
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateY(50%);
    }
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.header-unit {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

#video-container {
  position: absolute;
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video-container p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  /* additional */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
  <div id="video-container">
    <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
       <source src="https://coverr.co/s3/mp4/Into_the_Wild.mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Method #2

1. Offsetting position within containing element with `left` and
   `right` property values of `0`
2. Centering text with `text-align: center`
3. Defining height of nested `p` element to vertically center using `top` and `right` property values of `0`

**Example:**

```
#video-container p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  /* additional */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 58px;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.header-unit {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

#video-container {
  position: absolute;
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video-container p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  /* additional */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 58px;
}

video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
  <div id="video-container">
    <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
       <source src="https://coverr.co/s3/mp4/Into_the_Wild.mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Method #3

1. Declaring `display: flex` on containing parent element
2. Declaring further `flex-box` styles to containing element as required (see example for details)
3. Resetting `margin` property value on nested `p` for vertical centering

**Example:**

```
video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.header-unit {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

#video-container {
  position: absolute;
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* additional */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#video-container p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black; /* for the sake of demonstration */
  /* additional */
  margin: auto;
}

video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-unit">
  <div id="video-container">
    <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
       <source src="https://coverr.co/s3/mp4/Into_the_Wild.mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help with what you're looking for. I've added background and borders just for ease; you can remove them in your use.

```css
.header-unit {
       height: 200px;
       border: 2px solid #000;
       margin-top: 50px;
       position: relative;
       padding: 20px;
       background: #CCC;
     }
     
     #video-container {
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       border: 1px solid blue;
     }

     #video-container p {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 1;
       font-size: 50px;
       color: white;
       margin: 0;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       border: 1px solid red;
       width: 85%;
       text-align: center;
     }

     video {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 0;
       border: 1px solid green;
     }
     video.fillWidth {
      width: 100%;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="header-unit">
        <div id="video-container">
            <p>Next Event: December 10th</p>
            <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
              <source src="Forest.mov" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `#video-container` and `#video-container p` style with this code:

```
#video-container {
       top:0%;
       left:0%;
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-align: center;
}

#video-container p {
       width:auto;
       margin: auto;
       z-index: 1;
       font-size: 50px;
       color: white;
       line-height: 80px;
}
```

EDIT: Try this:

```
#video-container p {
       position: absolute;  //set this to be able to place it anywhere
       top: 5%;  //calculate this value based on your video block's height
       left: 5%; //calculate this value based on your video block's width
       z-index: 1;
       font-size: 50px;
       color: white;
}
```

Comment: It has centered the text, but the text is not in front of the image, it is above it.

Comment: @SamAvenell Happy to help :) If your problem is solved, can you mark this answer? To close the question.